# Can I read downloaded https://cssreference.io/ source code offline with Chrome?

Tags: html

I have downloaded the source code https://github.com/jgthms/css-reference for https://cssreference.io/.

After I expand the zipped folder and open the index.html file with Chrome, the browser doesn't render the page correctly. The index.html looks like the following:

```html
  {% include favicons.html %}
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="header-figure">
        <img src="{{site.url}}/images/css-reference-icon.png" alt="{{site.title}} icon">
        <img src="{{site.url}}/images/css-reference-type.png" alt="{{site.title}} type">
      </h1>
      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-carbon">
          {% include carbon.html %}
        </div>
        <div class="header-text">
          <h2 class="header-title">
            {{site.subtitle}}
          </h2>
          <p class="header-subtitle">
            <strong>Learn by example</strong>: <a href="{{site.url}}">cssreference.io</a> is a free visual guide to CSS. It features the most popular <strong>properties</strong>, and explains them with illustrated and animated <strong>examples</strong>.
          </p>
          <footer class="header-share">
            {% include social/button-twitter.html %}
            {% include social/button-facebook.html %}
```

Question: Is it possible that I can read this document offline with Chrome? Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` / `yarn` to install packages, and use `npm start` / `yarn start` for starting the project?

Comment: I just downloaded the zipped package and then load the index.html with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that you can read this document offline (or in other words, run the project's website), but it requires some steps that I've described below. (Disclaimer: `yarn` is used as package manager and macOS as OS, and it might be that you bump into different errors)

##### Steps

1. Update node-sass
2. Install Jekyll
3. Setup Jekyll in project
4. Serve project

##### Result

[image: CSS Reference running on localhost]

##### Why Jekyll?

The [`package.json`](https://github.com/jgthms/css-reference/blob/master/package.json) gives some clues about how it should be done, since one of the keywords is [`jekyll`](https://github.com/jgthms/css-reference/blob/master/package.json#L17). That means the project uses [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), a static site generator, and we should install it to run the project on our local machine.

##### 1. Update node-sass

Before we do anything with `jekyll`, we need to update the `node-sass` library inside the `package.json` file, since the project is quite old. Since my machine uses Node.js v14, we need to update `node-sass` to `4.14`, [according to its docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy).

```sh
yarn add node-sass@4.14
```

Your package.json should now include the following packages:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "node-sass": "4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^2.6.0"
  }
```

Be sure to run `yarn` to install all packages.

##### 2. Install Jekyll

Next step is to [install Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/), one of the requirements to run Jekyll is to have version 2.5 or higher of Ruby installed, [according to their docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#requirements).

```sh
brew install ruby
```

I followed the detailed instructions at the [*Step by Step Tutorial*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/).

Install jekyll and bundler with this command:

```sh
gem install jekyll bundler
```

##### 3. Setup Jekyll in project

Create a new `Gemfile` inside the project's folder to list your project’s dependencies:

```sh
bundle init
```

Edit the Gemfile in a text editor and add jekyll as a dependency:

```sh
gem "jekyll"
```

I needed to add `webrick` as another dependency in my Gemfile, because I ran into errors ([described here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523)), you can install it via:

```sh
gem install webrick
```

The Gemfile will now look something like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem "jekyll"

gem "webrick", "~> 1.7"
```

##### 4. Serve project

You have to restart your terminal (important step) and then run `bundle` inside your project folder to initialize jekyll it for your project.

With `jekyll serve`, you can now run the project on your local environment, port 4000 is set as the default. Some output from `jekyll serve` command:

```sh
css-reference-master jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/roy/Downloads/css-reference-master/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/roy/Downloads/css-reference-master
       Destination: /Users/roy/Downloads/css-reference-master/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.461 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/roy/Downloads/css-reference-master'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2022-01-08 22:09:07
                    .idea/workspace.xml
                    ...done in 0.528404 seconds.
```

See below for the proof of the project running on localhost.

[image: Project running on localhost]